# Why am I getting a negative value for the mass of this cut off cone with variable density?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am given a set $G=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3: x^2+y^2\le (2-z)^2, 0 \le z \le1 \}$ and a variable density

$$\rho(x,y,z)=\frac{-2 \cosh{(2-z)^2}}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})}$$

and I want to integrate: $\int_S \rho(x,y,z) dS$

Switching to cylindrical coordinates $G \rightarrow S$ I get:

$S=\{(r,\phi,z) \in \mathbb R^3:r \le 2-z, \phi \in [0, 2 \pi], 0 \le z \le 1 \}$

and $\rho=\frac{-2 \cosh{(2-z)^2}}{(r)}$

My integral then becomes: $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_0^{(2-z)} \frac{-2 \cosh{(2-z)^2}}{r} rdr dzd\phi \\ =2\pi\int_0^1 -2\cosh{\left((2-z)^2\right)}\cdot(2-z)dz \\ = 2\pi \sinh\left((2-z)^2\right)|_0^1=2\pi \sinh{1}-2\pi\sinh{4} <0$$

Since mass can't be less than zero I am sure I did something wrong but I am not sure where. Maybe the bounds of integration should be reversed in the innermost integral but I don't just want to change random things to get the correct sign.

Comment: Why is your density function negative to begin with?

Comment: @Quanto It's written like that on the problem set. I triple checked and there is a minus.

Comment: But if you have a negative mass density, then the mass of a thing with positive volume is negative. Whether negative mass makes physical sense is another question.

Comment: Clearly, integrating negative density will yield negative mass :-)

Comment: Yeah makes sense. I was just confused that someone would specify a negative mass density. Seems unphysical to me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does the problem ever describe $\rho$ as a *mass* density? The term "density" is used to describe a large variety of things, and many of them (charge density, for another physical example) can be negative. There are also situations where a negative mass density makes sense: when there is a background mass distribution and you are tracking variations from it (I often deal with negative masses for a similar reason).